# New features for windows workflow foundation 5

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation

What new features are planned for WWF 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my PDC10 Talk [Windows Workflow Foundation Futures](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT08)